# Toggle button looping, but mousup not

Tags: jquery, button, drop-down-menu, toggle

I'm stuck trying to get this toggle button dropdown to work. I want it to drop and fade in when clicked and hide with clicked again. It works when I click outside the area, the box hides, and it works when I click the button the first time the box drops in. When I click the button to hide it, the box hides but doesn't stay hidden it immediately shows again.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".signin").click(function(e) {          
            e.preventDefault();
            $("div#dropdown_container").animate({opacity: "show", top: "45"}, "slow");
            $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");

        });

        $("div#dropdown_container").mouseup(function() {
            return false
        });
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).parent(".signin").length==0) {
                $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
                $("div#dropdown_container").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "75"}, "fast");
            }
        });         
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).parent(".signin menu-open").length==0) {
                $("menu-open").removeClass(".signin");
                $("div#dropdown_container").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "75"}, "fast");
            }
        }); 
    });
```

I'm just a beginner at jquery so any help would be appreciated, if it helps this code was modified from this http://aext.net/2009/08/perfect-sign-in-dropdown-box-likes-twitter-with-jquery/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "div#dropdown_container" is visible or hidden before display it.

```
    $(".signin").click(function(e) {          
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($("#dropdown_container").is(":hidden")){
            $("#dropdown_container").animate({opacity: "show", top: "45"}, "slow");
        }

        $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");

    });
```